# Array of paths from Nested Hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-hash

I have a hash

```
my_hash = {"key1"=> {"key2"=> {"key3"=> "value"}}, "key4"=>  "value"}
```

I want to return only the full path of the keys as an array. All concatenated like this

```
[key1, key1key2, key1key2key3, key4].
```

Any suggestions on how to do this. Thanks

Comment: and what you try fo far?

Comment: https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor

Comment: @mudasobwa: +1 for cool gem name. "meh" for method names. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it’s monkeypatching `Hash` and `Array`. I needed to be 102% sure there is no clash. In any case, in version `1.0` it’ll have a normal syntax with delegation via `hash.iteraptor_en.map {}`, `hash.iteraptor_es.mapa {}`, and `hash.iteraptor_ru.замаппить {}`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev FWIW, it has the sibling for Elixir https://github.com/am-kantox/elixir-iteraptor

Comment: @mudasobwa: mind you, I don't have better name suggestions. But it should be _something_ in english. I don't know about you, but switching languages every two words breaks reading flow for me ("wait, what language was that? Looked like spanish, but I'm not sure. I need to go back and re-read."). While I smile at замаппить, it's even worse. Barely better than string of emoji :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: yep, that delegation looks nice!

Comment: Speaking of strange method names: [`Sidekiq.❨╯°□°❩╯︵┻━┻`](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/873f1df9e0171a6eb1f9e6f50152f78e045b6df5/lib/sidekiq.rb#L52)

Comment: @Stefan I like (and use) [this](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/2ed92600fa71a9c275189d01df369ad4f8b9ca32/lib/sidekiq/api.rb#L279).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor#boring-for-users-who-are-too-conservative thanks for pinging me for doing that :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: Much better 

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve this with the [iteraptor](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor) helpers suggested by this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2035262/mudasobwa). Thanks

I used the feature 'aplanar' i.e

```
hash.aplanar.keys
```

returns the paths of all the keys that have values. Just as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a recursive method that progressively modifies the keys of inner hashes. For example,

```
{"key2"=> {"key3"=> "value"}}
```

is changed to

```
{"key1key2"=> {"key3"=> "value"}}
```

after which

```
{"key3"=> "value"}
```

is changed to

```
{"key1key2key3"=> "value"}
```

This allows me to simply accumulate the keys of these hashes.

```
def recurse(h)
  h.map do |k,v|
    next k unless v.is_a?(Hash)
    key, val = v.flatten
    [k, recurse("#{k}#{key}"=>val)]
  end.flatten
end

recurse my_hash
  #=> ["key1", "key1key2", "key1key2key3", "key4"]
```

Comment: I always try to avoid the use of the method `Array#flatten`, simply because I find it ugly. I welcome suggestions for how I can do away with it here. Changing `map` to `flat_map` is not sufficient.